# Assign value to item inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have a list of players using *ngFor

```js
// Get all players.
getPlayers() {
  this.httpService.getPlayers()
  .subscribe(
    player => {
      this.players = player;

      for (let i in this.players){
        if(this.players[i].Main_Image_ID){
          this.getPlayerIMG(this.players[i].Main_Image_ID);
        }
      }
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

```html
<div ion-item *ngFor="let player of players">
  <img *ngIf="player?.playerIMG" width="50" [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+playerIMG" />
  <img *ngIf="!player?.playerIMG" width="50" src="./assets/images/no-image.jpg" />
  {{player.First_Name}} {{player.Last_Name}}
</div>
```

The value returned by the API call returns an array of objects with multiple players. Every player has some info and an imageID. After I subscribe to the call and get the players, the list will be populated. I then call another API to get the image, using the imageID. My objective is to after I know all the players, and their imageID, to populate the respective player on the list with their image.

```js
// Get image for player.
getPlayerIMG(id) {
  this.httpService.getPlayerIMG(id)
  .subscribe(
    playerIMG => {
      this.player.playerIMG = playerIMG;
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

The question is how can I assign the response of every imageID call to the respective item(player) on the list(players).

Thank you!

Comment: Your getPlayerIMG function should return a promise instead of an observable, and needs to be chained when its called, using .then() After the promise resolves/rejects, you're able to set their proper image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to write a component for player but you can use this code and  pass a player to function instead of Main_Image_ID

```
for (let i in this.players){
    if(this.players[i].Main_Image_ID){
      this.getPlayerIMG(this.players[i]);
    }
}

// Get image for player.
getPlayerIMG(player) {
   this.httpService.getPlayerIMG(player.Main_Image_ID)
   .subscribe(
      playerIMG => {
        player.playerIMG = playerIMG;
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```